VTK not being recognized by QtCreator in QML
I've been struggling to include VTK into QML. I have installed VTK 9.3 through ninja, following the Kitware's gitlab docs. I also have set env variables QML_IMPORT_PATH and QML_IMPORT_PATH to VTKInstallation/lib/qml/vtk-9.3. Everything seems to be working, except QTCreator not identifying VTK qml Components
Here is my CmakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(hii VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
find_package(Qt6 6.5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Quick OpenGL)
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

qt_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES 6.5)

qt_add_executable(apphii
    main.cpp
)
qt_add_qml_module(apphii
    URI hii
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        Main.qml
)
set_target_properties(apphii PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)
target_link_libraries(apphii
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick
    ${QT_LIBRARIES}
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
    ${VTK_LIBRARIES}
)
include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS apphii
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

Now, my Main.qml contains these VTK lines:
import VTK 9.3  # imports just fine!
...
VTKRenderWindow { # Unknown Component (M300)
      id: vtkwindow
      width: 400
      height: 400
    }

The code runs without any problems, nonetheless the qtcreator doesn't seem to recognize the module's components.
BTW, the directory VTKInstallation/lib/qml/vtk-9.3 contains qmldir and plugins.qmltypes:
qmldir file:
module VTK
plugin qmlvtkplugin
classname QQmlVTKPlugin
typeinfo plugins.qmltypes

plugins.qmltypes file:
import QtQuick.tooling 1.2

// This file describes the plugin-supplied types contained in the library.
// It is used for QML tooling purposes only.
//
// This file was auto-generated by:
// 'qmlplugindump -output $qmldir/VTK.9.1/plugins.qmltypes VTK 9.1 $qmldir'

Module {
    dependencies: ["QtQuick 2.0"]
    Component {
        name: "QQuickVTKInteractiveWidget"
        prototype: "QObject"
        exports: ["VTKWidget 9.1"]
        exportMetaObjectRevisions: [0]
        Property { name: "enabled"; type: "bool" }
        Signal {
            name: "enabledChanged"
            Parameter { name: "e"; type: "bool" }
        }
        Method {
            name: "sync"
            Parameter { name: "ren"; type: "vtkRenderer"; isPointer: true }
        }
    }
    Component {
        name: "QQuickVTKRenderItem"
        defaultProperty: "data"
        prototype: "QQuickItem"
        exports: ["VTKRenderItem 9.1"]
        exportMetaObjectRevisions: [0]
        Property { name: "renderWindow"; type: "QQuickVTKRenderWindow"; isPointer: true }
        Method { name: "sync" }
        Method { name: "init" }
        Method { name: "paint" }
        Method { name: "cleanup" }
    }
    Component {
        name: "QQuickVTKRenderWindow"
        defaultProperty: "data"
        prototype: "QQuickItem"
        exports: ["VTKRenderWindow 9.1"]
        exportMetaObjectRevisions: [0]
        Method { name: "sync" }
        Method { name: "init" }
        Method { name: "paint" }
        Method { name: "cleanup" }
        Method { name: "renderNow" }
        Method { name: "render" }
    }
}

Would someone please why QTCreator doesn't know about the components?
Thank you very much in advance
Regards
